# How do I get the touchpad on a MBP 7,1 working?

Tags: 11.04, touchpad, mac

I upgraded from Ubuntu 10.10 to Ubuntu 11.04 and now my touchpad doesn't work. Please explain how to fix it thoroughly, because I'm a newbie. Thanks

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it.

Comment: I just copied into the terminal 1) sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Comment: And then 2) I edited what I already had on the file:       Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "enable synaptics SHMConfig"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "SHMConfig" "on"
EndSection

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem upgrading from ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04. I used the Synaptic drivers in 10.10, but the solution that worked the best for me was to **REMOVE** all mention of the Synaptics Touchpad diver and Device settings for the touchpad from the **xorg.conf** file. 
Rebooted and the Touchpad worked perfectly with the default ubuntu touchpad drivers. The settings also appear under the mouse settings for the touchpad by default after install on the MBP 7,1

The same holds true for the Apple Magic Trackpad used with Ubuntu 11.04. It works perfectly out of the box with multi finger gestures.